# Getting back the value of a `cleared` input element with React Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a several `ReactSelect` components, and one piece of global state which is responsible for holding all my selected values in an array.

**Select**

```
      <Select
        styles={inputStyles}
        className="basic-single"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        isClearable={true}
        isSearchable={false}
        placeholder={'Select Your Most Convenient Time Slot'}
        options={newHoursArr}
        isMulti={false}
        onChange={(values) => handleChange(values)}

        defaultValue={clientServiceReferral.selectedTimeSlots.map((referral) => (
          referral.timeSlot === timeWithDate ? (
            { ['label']: referral.value, ['value']: referral.value }
          ) : null
        ))}
      />
```

**handleChange function**

```
  const handleChange = (value) => {

    const found = clientServiceReferral.selectedTimeSlots.find(element => element.timeSlot === timeWithDate);

    if (found) {
      clientServiceReferral.selectedTimeSlots.splice(found, 1)
    }

    const newValue = {
      timeSlot: timeWithDate,
      value: value.value
    }

    setClientServiceReferral({
      ...clientServiceReferral,
      selectedTimeSlots: [...clientServiceReferral.selectedTimeSlots, newValue]
    })
  }
```

`ReactSelect` has an `isClearable` prop. Which allows users to clear the input with a button click. This returns a value of `null` when `values` is logged in the `onChange` function, but is there a way to return the actual value inside the select that is getting cleared when the clear button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an optional second parameter passed to the `onChange` event. It's of this type:

```js
export interface ActionMetaBase<Option> {
  option?: Option | undefined;
  removedValue?: Option;
  removedValues?: Options<Option>;
  name?: string;
}
```

Now, I've never used this library, but it looks like `removedValue` or `removedValues` could be helpful? idk.

Anyway, I got that from [their docs](https://react-select.com/typescript#onchange). Hope it works out for you:

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, Via Joshua Wood's answer, the value of any cleared item(s) can be found as so:

```
onChange={(values, removedValue) => handleChange(values, removedValue)}
```

```
  const handleChange = (value, removedValue) => {

    if (removedValue.action === 'clear') {
      console.log('removed', removedValue.removedValues[0])
    }
// removedValues returns an array
```